# How prove this sum $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(2k-1)!!\left(\binom{n-1}{2k-2}-n\binom{n-2}{2k-1}-\binom{n-2}{2k}\right)=1$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

For any  positive integer $n>1$ show that this sum
$$F(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(2k-1)!!\left(\binom{n-1}{2k-2}-n\binom{n-2}{2k-1}-\binom{n-2}{2k}\right)=1$$

where if $n>m$ then $\binom{m}{n}=0$

My try:
it is clear $$F(2)=1!!(\binom{1}{1}-0-0)=1$$
and
$$F(3)=1!!(\binom{2}{0}-3\binom{1}{1}-0)+3!!(\binom{2}{2}-0-0)=1$$
$$F(4)=1!!(\binom{3}{0}-4\binom{2}{1}-\binom{2}{2})+3!!(\binom{3}{2}-0-0)=1$$
and $F(5)=1,F(6)=1$,But How to $F(n)=1,\forall n\in N^{+}$,I have note
$$(n-1)\ge 2k-2,n-2\ge 2k-1,n-2\ge 2k$$,so we have $k\le [\dfrac{n+1}{2}],k\le [\dfrac{n-1}{2}],k\le [\dfrac{n-2}{2}]$

Comment: For lots more of something similar ... see https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.1317.pdf

Answer (score 4):

We show for $n\geq 2$ the validity of $F(n)=1$ with the help of generating functions. It is somewhat more convenient to consider $F(n+2)$ instead of $F(n)$ and we claim:

> The following is valid for $n\geq 0$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k\geq 1}\left(\binom{n+1}{2k-2}-(n+2)\binom{n}{2k-1}-\binom{n}{2k}\right)(2k-1)!!=1}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

The sum (1) is finite since $\binom{p}{q}=0$ for $p,q$ non-negative integers with $q>p$. We use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^q]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^q$ in a series. We consider each of the parts at the left-hand side of (1) separately and put them together at the end.

> **First part:** We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+3}{2}\right\rfloor}}&\color{blue}{\binom{n+1}{2k-2}(2k-1)!!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+3}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{(n+1)!}{(2k-2)!(n+3-2k)!}\,\frac{(2k )!}{(2k)!!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+3}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+3-2k)!}\,\frac{2k(2k-1)}{2^kk!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+3}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+3-2k)!}\,\frac{2k-1}{2^{k-1}(k-1)!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1-2k)!}\,\frac{2k+1}{2^kk!}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1-2k)!}\,\frac{1}{2^{k-1}(k-1)!}
> +\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1-2k)!}\,\frac{1}{2^{k}k!}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{(n+1)!}{(n-1-2k)!}\,\frac{1}{2^{k}k!}
> +\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1-2k)!}\,\frac{1}{2^{k}k!}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(n+1)!\left([z^{n-1}]+[z^{n+1}]\right)\exp\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we shift the index $k$ by one and start with $k=0$.
- In (3) we split the sums according to $2k+1$ and cancel at the left-hand sum. Since the term with $k=0$ is zero at the left-hand sum, we start with $k=1$.
- In (4) we shift the index $k$ of the left-hand sum by one.
- In (5) we observe we have the coefficients $[z^{n-1}]$ and $[z^{n+1}]$ of $\exp\left(z\right)\exp\left(\frac{z^2}{2}\right)=\exp\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)$. The derivation for it is similar to that of the third part and is shown there.

> **Second part:** We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor}}&\color{blue}{\binom{n}{2k-1}(2k-1)!!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{n!}{(2k-1)!(n+1-2k)!}\,\frac{(2k )!}{(2k)!!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{n!}{(n+1-2k)!}\,\frac{2k}{2^kk!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{n!}{(n+1-2k)!}\,\frac{1}{2^{k-1}(k-1)!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{n!}{(n-1-2k)!}\,\frac{1}{2^kk!}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=n![z^{n-1}]\exp\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (6) we observe we have a coefficient of $[z^{n-1}]$ of $\exp\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)$. The derivation for it is similar to that of the third part and is shown there.

> **Third part:** The third part is very similar to the parts before, but it has additionally a nice twist which provides us with the **constant $1$**. We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}}&\color{blue}{\binom{n}{2k}(2k-1)!!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{n!}{(2k)!(n-2k)!}\,\frac{(2k )!}{(2k)!!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{n!}{(n-2k)!}\,\frac{1}{2^kk!}\tag{7}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=n![z^{n}]\left(\exp\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)-\exp(z)\right)}\tag{8}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (8) we have the funny intermediate result:
  \begin{align*}
  n![z^{n}]\exp(z)=n![z^n]\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{z^j}{j!}\color{blue}{=1}
  \end{align*}

and the further procedure is clear: We expect that the sum of the coefficients of $\exp\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)$ cancel away leaving the constant $n![z^{n}]\exp(z)=1$. But at first we have to show the validity of (8).

> **Derivation of (8):** We get
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\exp}&\color{blue}{\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)-\exp(z)}\\
> &=\exp(z)\left(\exp\left(\frac{z^2}{2}\right)-1\right)\\
> &=\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{z^j}{j!}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^{2k}}{2^kk!}\right)\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{{j+2k=n}\atop{j\geq 0, k\geq 1}}\frac{1}{j!}\,\frac{1}{2^kk!}\right)z^n\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{n!}{(n-2k)!}\,\frac{1}{2^kk!}\right)\frac{z^n}{n!}}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (8) follows.

Now it's (nearly) time to harvest. Let's collect the representation of the parts (5),(6) and (8) we have so far:

> **Final step:** We obtain from (1), (5), (6) and (8)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k\geq 1}}&\color{blue}{\left(\binom{n+1}{2k-2}-(n+2)\binom{n}{2k-1}-\binom{n}{2k}\right)(2k-1)!!}\\
> &=(n+1)!\left([z^{n-1}]+[z^{n+1}]\right)\exp\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\\
> &\qquad-(n+2)n![z^{n-1}]\exp\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\\
> &\qquad-n![z^{n}]\left(\exp\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)-\exp(z)\right)\\
> &=\left((n+1)![z^{n+1}]-n![z^n]-n![z^{n-1}]\right)\exp\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\color{blue}{+1}\tag{9}
> \end{align*}

We want to show the coefficients in (9) cancel away. In order to do so, we consider
\begin{align*}
A(z)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n=\exp\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\\
\\
\frac{d}{dz}A(z)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nz^{n-1}\tag{10}\\
\frac{d}{dz}\exp\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)&=(1+z)\exp\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\tag{11}\\
\end{align*}

> Coefficient comparison of (10) and (11) gives:
> \begin{align*}
> (n+1)a_{n+1}&=\color{blue}{(n+1)[z^{n+1}]A(z)}\\
> &=[z^n](1+z)\exp\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\left([z^n]+[z^{n-1}]\right)A(z)}
> \end{align*}
> which shows that in (9)
> \begin{align*}
> \left((n+1)![z^{n+1}]-n![z^n]-n![z^{n-1}]\right)\exp\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}\right)=0
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.